# holy grial layout with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I just use `flex` for layout, the markup like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell"></div>
</div>
```

and the normal view like this:

[layout structure - default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqLch.png)

when in a breakpoint, view like this:

[layout structure - responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sYdy.png)

the problem is, do not change the markup and just use `flex`, how can I make this?

Comment: Well, you can keep the markup but change flex and go display:block; with some other rules?

Comment: code demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/vehm499h/, but it still doesn't work :<, it have tried it before... @FaustoNA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flex, you may use min-width to set a breaking-point.
example with 2 childs at:

```
min-width:200px;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
flex:1
```

makes a first break point at 200px + 40px margin + 40px padding = ~ 480px (mind borders too or reset `box-sizing` properties)**inside** the flex container  .

---

**Example with your structure breaking at average 750px**

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid;
}
.grid div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
  min-width: 200px;
  /* from 3 childs: avearge breaking points */
  /* first breaking-point at 200 x 3 + padding/margin = 730px within flex-container */
  /*second breaking-point at 200 x 2 + padding/margin = 480px within flex-container */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about auto width? @GCyrillus

Comment: @user2548744 try it too :) maybe less flexible if only width set